# How do we feel about client solicitations as answers?

Tags: discussion

I'm referring specifically to [this answer here](https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/792/1114). Is this allowed, and should it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question itself was somewhat borderline except that it was obliquely asking for techniques to save on the legal costs associated with the patent process. The question itself may still turn out to be off topic, but I had to remove that answer as a direct (albeit solicited) commercial post.

Comment: OK, so then client solicitation isn't allowed. I didn't think it was, but couldn't find any specific rule against it.